# I need to parse the table with dota2protracker Python

Tags: python, html, css

It is not possible to parse the table from the site with the winrates of all the heroes. Can you tell me how to find this table or a link to it?
https://dota2protracker.com/meta

In Python, it returns "none" when attempting a request.I can't find the link through the page code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they publish any public webapi. But you can try to do what it does: query the DOTA webapi for pro matches, aggregate the data and calculate the output to closely resemble what D2 ProTracker does. Of course, in order to do that you'll need your own SDK API key for the webapi.

You can use this framework for logging matches: https://github.com/ayousif00/Dota2ProTracker (no guarantees that it's the same one though, but it should be fine to get you started).

Keep in mind the template is 7 years old so you might have to work a bit on updating it (I am assuming it won't have the latest heroes).